# Disable recording IP address in google app engine logs

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to make configurations in Google app engine for not recording IP addresses from clients to the Java application in stackdriver logs?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot configure or opt-out from request logs, where the client IP addresses are recorded. From [Using Stackdriver Logging in App Engine apps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging):

> The App Engine standard environment produces the following logs:
>
> - **Request logs**, `appengine.googleapis.com/request_log`, called `request_log` in the Logs Viewer. This log records requests sent to
>     all App Engine apps. The request log is provided by default and you
>     cannot opt out of receiving it. For more details, see the [RequestLog
>     type](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/ref/rest/v1beta3/RequestLog).
>
> ...
>
> The App Engine flexible environment produces the following logs:
>
> - **Request logs** record requests sent to all App Engine apps. The request log is provided by default and you cannot opt out of receiving
>     it.

Comment: You can use sinks to filter out the request logs in general. So you won't have the ip adresses there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68607220/google-app-engine-disable-request-logging/72895859#72895859